# Transaction (Process ID 98) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

As far as i understand, this exception is thrown because multiple of my threads try to access the same data on the database. But the exception is thrown in a line where i convert an enumerable to a list.

Can anyone explain this?

(The Program.GetContext(), is used to get the current threads context to the database, since it's multithreaded, and uses EF this is a way to do it)

```
var loadedSammenSat = Program.GetContext().SammensatKodetVaerdier.Where(o => (o.Kode == kode) && (o.Kodetekst == kodetekst) && (o.Forkortelse == forkortelse) && (o.Navn == navn)).Include(b => b.Tillaegskode).ToList();


    if (!sammensatKodet.Tillaegskode.Any())
    {
        var selceted = loadedSammenSat.FirstOrDefault(o => (o.Tillaegskode == null || o.Tillaegskode.Count == 0));
        if (selceted != null)
            return selceted;
    }
    else
    {
        var selcetedWithOutList = loadedSammenSat.Where(o => (o.Tillaegskode != null && o.Tillaegskode.Count() == sammensatKodet.Tillaegskode.Count()));
        var selceted = selcetedWithOutList.ToList(); //LINE THAT THROW EXCEPTION!!
        if (selceted.Count() > 0)
        {
            List<DBTillaegsKode> list = new List<DBTillaegsKode>();
            sammensatKodet.Tillaegskode.ForEach(p => list.Add(new DBTillaegsKode(p.KodetVaerdi)));

            foreach (var dbSammensatKodetVaerdi in selceted)
            {
                var mismatch = dbSammensatKodetVaerdi.Tillaegskode.Except(list);
                if(mismatch.GetEnumerator().Current != null)
                    if (mismatch.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        return dbSammensatKodetVaerdi;
                    }  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using deferred queries. Up until that line you don't actually hit the database, you just build up a query to use when it actually hits the database. `ToList()` will force the query to execute in order to return the list, and that's when you get the problem.

Comment: Start by reading [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: how often does the deadlock occur? is it every time, or is it sporadic?

Comment: the program has been running fine for weeks, but now i get this every time i run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ is lazy-loaded - it's only when you do something with the resultset (in this case doing a `.ToList()` operation) that the query is executed.